# Is it possible to define schema in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I know MongoDB is schemaless. However, I have data model for some objects/entities and I have a well defined set of attributes that they will contain. For eg, If I have a Student entity, I know its json looks like

```
{
  name: "string",
  id: "int",
  class: "string"
}
```

Is it possible to define this schema using MongoDB?
If this isn't possible, then how can I validate if the user has sent the complete set for creating a new student?

Comment: you can check out ORM tool named "Kundera(https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera)". It also facilitates to query in JPA way like "select s from student s"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongodb is not a magical solution which work for all problems. One of it's strength is schemaless, so if you have collections that have absolutely fixed schema - then consider using other sql dbs (you will get rid of a lot of overhead).

If you really want to define schema - it is not possible to do this in vanilla mongo, but as with many popular technologies there are a loot of libraries available. One of them which allows to define schema is [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). It is not the only one and you will find a lot of similar tools.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var blogSchema = new Schema({
  title:  String,
  author: String,
  body:   String,
  comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  hidden: Boolean,
  meta: {
    votes: Number,
    favs:  Number
  }
});
```

**P.S.** if you do not want to use any additional library, you can define your schema in your application layer and validate each document before adding it to db, but before jumping into a new technology, it is nice to see whether it makes a good fit. Using technology for the sake of using technology is never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDb by definition is a schema less database, so there is no way from the database end to verify that the user has sent the complete set or not.

For implementing this requirement you will need to implement it at the Application layer and make your application schema aware.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is not able to validate or enforce a schema.

However you can create your own schema validation on the client side. Before you let your client insert a new JSON document into your student collection you can check the document, that it only contains your given Keys containing the appropriate data types and prevent the insert if the data restrictions are not meet.

Also object document mapper (ODM) like [Spring-Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/) can enforce this type of validation depending on the Client (Java in this case) you are using.

[Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) could be used for Node.js

Answer (score 1):

### MongoDB 3.6 (released 2017) adds the `$jsonSchema` operator to support document validation using JSON Schema.

[**MongoDB docs reference**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#mongodb-query-op.-jsonSchema)

The `$jsonSchema` operator matches documents that satisfy the specified JSON Schema.

For example:

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
     required: [ "name", "major", "gpa", "address" ],
     properties: {
        name: {
           bsonType: "string",
           description: "must be a string and is required"
        },
        address: {
           bsonType: "object",
           required: [ "zipcode" ],
           properties: {
               "street": { bsonType: "string" },
               "zipcode": { bsonType: "string" }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

You can use `$jsonSchema` in a **document validator** to enforce the specified schema on **insert and update operations**:

```
db.createCollection( <collection>, { validator: { $jsonSchema: <schema> } } )
db.runCommand( { collMod: <collection>, validator:{ $jsonSchema: <schema> } } )
```

You can use `$jsonSchema` in **query conditions for read and write operations** to find documents in the collection that satisfy the specified schema:

```
db.collection.find( { $jsonSchema: <schema> } )
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $match: { $jsonSchema: <schema> } } ] )
db.collection.updateMany( { $jsonSchema: <schema> }, <update> )
db.collection.deleteOne( { $jsonSchema: <schema> } )
```

To find documents in the collection that **do not** satisfy the specified schema, use the `$jsonSchema` expression in a `$nor` expression. For example:

```
db.collection.find( { $nor: [ { $jsonSchema: <schema> } ] } )
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $match: { $nor: [ { $jsonSchema: <schema> } ] } }, ... ] )
db.collection.updateMany( { $nor: [ { $jsonSchema: <schema> } ] }, <update> )
db.collection.deleteOne( { $nor: [ { $jsonSchema: <schema> } ] } )
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found the following meteor package to be really helpful:
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema